# In Google Cloud Platform, with a python 3.8 back-end and an angular front-end, with no user login implemented, how do I get the current user?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-identity

I am implementing a service in a Google App Engine environment, with a Python 3.8 back-end (using Flask) and an Angular 11 front end.  I am not using any login, so the service http address goes directly into the application.  I am relying on the Google Identity Aware Proxy to secure my site.  How do I get the current user (either id or name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the headers

From [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto)

....IAP also passes the user's identity to your backend service in the following HTTP headers.

`X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email  The user's email address`

`X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Id A persistent, unique identifier for the user.`

Comment: this was very helpful, and if you just want the nickname of the user, this header works: X-Appengine-User-Nickname